# PrimeFaces AJAX-commandButton produces a non-AJAX request depending on its process attribute

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I’m using buttons that look like this:

```
<p:commandButton
    partialSubmit="true"
    process="@(.ui-selection-column)"
    update="mainForm"
    action="#{requestBean.arise()}"
    title="@(.ui-selection-column) / mainForm"
    value="arise"/>
```

**If they are on a page containing elements of the class specified in process selector** (ui-selection-column in the previous snippet) **then the request is a non-AJAX request; otherwise it is an AJAX request, as expected**.

I tried with several pages using different classes and I got the same result. So I don’t think the problem is related to specific pages and/or classes. In particular, I tried adding the button to pages with a dataTable with a selection column defined in it (checkboxes in such column have the ui-selection-column class). Then I monitored every request with a RESTORE_VIEW phase listener and determined if the request was or not an AJAX request calling facesContext.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest() in its beforePhase method.

My listener looks like this:

```
public class RestoreViewListener implements PhaseListener {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RestoreViewListener.class);
    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
    }
    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (facesContext.getRenderResponse()) {
        } else {
            boolean ajaxRequest = facesContext.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest();
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
            DispatcherType dispatcherType = request.getDispatcherType();
            String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
            logger.info((ajaxRequest ? "AJAX-" : "non-AJAX-") + dispatcherType + requestURI);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    }
}
```

And the listener definition in faces-config.xml looks like this:

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>
        web.app.RestoreViewListener
    </phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

Can anybody help me find a solution? Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: is `process="@(.ui-selection-column)"` pointing to real jsf compomemts with id's or just html elements

Comment: good question; I'll get back to you on that. I will have to see what is being generated by PrimeFaces

Comment: it is pointing to "td" elements, like this one:

Comment: <td class="ui-selection-column" role="gridcell" style="text-align: center; width: 1em">
        <div class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
            <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                <input name="mainForm:dataTable_checkbox" aria-checked="false" type="checkbox">
            </div>
            <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>

Comment: You cannot update plain html elements. Only things that have an ID in an xhtml file and even then only things that are real components with renderers (`p:columns not being one of them)

Comment: The button updates a form (with ID=mainForm), The AJAX/non-AJAX behavior depends on "process", not "update". Does "process" have the same restriction? If it does, would a violation of such restriction cause a non-AJAX request?